# mockito when with third party class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

I need to use a third party class in `Mockito.when` as parameter. The class does not have equals implementation and hence `Mockito.when` always returns `null` except the case where `any()` is used.

The below always returns null:

```
when(obj.process(new ThirdParytClass())).thenReturn(someObj);
```

however, this works

```
when(obj.process(any(ThirdParytClass.class))).thenReturn(someObj);
```

But, the problem is the `process()` method is called twice in the actual code and the use of `any()` is ambiguous and does not help in covering the multiple scenarios to test.

Extending the class does not help and also leads to other complications.

Is there a way to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If a class doesn't implement a (sensible) `equals(Object)`, you can always match instances yourself by implementing your own [`ArgumentMatcher`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html). Java 8's functional interfaces make this pretty easy to write (not that it was such a big hardship in earlier versions, but still):

```
when(obj.process(argThat(tpc -> someLogic()))).thenReturn(someObj);
```

More often than not, however, if you just want to compare the class' data members, the built-in [`refEq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#refEq(T,%20java.lang.String...)) matcher would do the trick:

```
ThirdParytClass expected = new ThirdParytClass();
// set the expected properties of expected

when(obj.process(refEq(expected))).thenReturn(someObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mockito provides the captor feature that may help you to bypass limitations of `equals()` method because overriding `equals()` to make a test pass may be desirable but it is not always the case.
And besides, sometimes, `equals()` may not be overridable. It is your use case.

Here is a example code with an `ArgumentCaptor` :

```
@Mock
MyMockedClass myMock;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor argCaptor;

@Test
public void yourTest() {
    ThirdPartyClass myArgToPass = new ThirdPartyClass();
    // call the object under test
     ...
    //
    Mockito.verify(myMock).process(argCaptor.capture());
    // assert the value of the captor argument is the expected onoe
    assertEquals(myArgToPass , argCaptor.getValue());
}
```